# Hostinger setup

Tags: php, mysql

I do not know what put in datasource. What does it mean by datasource? I am using hostinger for my server.  Thank you.

```
<?php
class DATABASE_CONFIG {
    public $default = array(
        'datasource' => '',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'mysql.hostinger.jp',
        'login' => 'u88_ana',
        'password' => 'secret',
        'database' => 'u88_vir',
        'encoding' => 'utf8'
    );
}
```

Comment: Hostinger has a live chat support. I guess.

Comment: They would be able to assist you better. Why don't you create a help token?